# When $x=2$ in the infinitely continued fraction $x+\frac{1}{x^2+\frac{1}{x^3+\ldots}}$, what algebraic value does it converge to?

Tags: continued-fractions

Say you have the infinitely continued fraction:
$$x+\cfrac{1}{x^2+\cfrac{1}{x^3+\cfrac{1}{x^4+\ddots}}}$$

When $x=1$, you can see that it's
$$1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\ddots}}}$$ which converges upon the **golden ratio** $\phi = 1.61803398875...$.

What if I were to plug in $x=2$?
$$2+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{8+\cfrac{1}{16+\ddots}}}$$
Using a caluclator, it seems to converge upon the irrational number: $2.24248109286...$

Is there any way I can represent this irrational number **algebraically**?

Comment: The chances are that you can't represent this number algebraically. The chances are that it is transcendental, like $\pi$, not algebraic, like $\root3\of2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Are you sure?

Comment: It has very good rational approximations. The theorem of Thue-Siegel-Roth says algebraic irrationals can't have rational approximations that are too good. That's where I'd recommend starting, if you want to try to prove the number is transcendental.

Answer (score 3):

Let $F(x)=x^0+\cfrac1{x^1+\cfrac1\cdots}~.$ Then $F(2)$ is [OEIS A$214070$](https://oeis.org/A214070), for which no closed form is currently known.

Comment: I haven studied these much but this question made me want to look into them. I'm wondering if there is a nice series representation of this continued fraction

Comment: There is a little more information at https://oeis.org/A096641